# How to evaluate grep result in bash?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to grep a specific status of a service (`tomcat8.service`).

Only if the string was found, I want to execute some logic.

Problem: even if I execute the script on service name that does not exist ("asd" in this example), the `if $status` still matches and prints out. But why?

```
status = $(systemctl status asd.service | grep 'active')
echo $status

if $status
then 
    echo "$SERVICE was active"
    exit 0
fi 
exit 0
```

Result output is: `asd.service was active`, which is certainly not true.

The `echo $status` prints: `status: Unknown job: =`

Comment: I would change the title of the question with *what* you want to achieve (i.e: execute a command depending on the status of a service), instead of *how* you thought you can do it (i.e: evaluating grep result). As the answer states, grep is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of grep's return status.

```
systemctl status asd.service | grep 'active' \
    && status=active \
    || status=not_active

if [ "$status" == "active" ]; then
    [...]
fi
```

or even easier:

```
test $(systemctl status asd.service | grep 'active') \
    && echo "$SERVICE was active"
```

or if you prefer `if`:

```
if $(systemctl status asd.service | grep 'active'); then
    echo "$SERVICE was active"
fi
```

Anyways, take care about the keywords `inactive`, `not active`, `active (exited)` or alike. This will also match your `grep` statement. See the comments. Thanks @ Terrance for the hint.

---

### Update:

No need for grep. `systemctl` has the command `is-active` included.

```
systemctl -q is-active asd.service \
    && echo "$SERVICE was active"
```

or:

```
if systemctl -q is-active asd.service; then
    echo "is active";
fi
```

Comment: As `if` uses the return code you can just use `if systemctl status asd.service | grep 'active'; then ...`

Comment: true. thanks for the hint, updated the answer. But $(...) is needed

Comment: The last suggestion works great!

Comment: The problem with doing `grep 'active'` is that it will find `inactive` as well as `active`.  `grep -w active` will find only `active` and ignore `inactive`.

Comment: Good point. But as OP used this `grep`, I assumed it was working in his case. `-w active` will also not work if the output was `not active`.

Comment: I don't think that I have seen `not active` but I have seen `active (exited)` vs `active (running)`.  I am thinking that OP needs more code to do this exactly.

Comment: how could we miss `systemctl is-active` ?

Comment: As I also want to evaluate `active (exited)` I cannot use `is-active`. Because I want to detect  `exited` is notactive...

Answer (score 1):

Some code review comments:

- sh/bash/ksh/zsh variable assignments look like `var=value` -- no spaces around the `=` are allowed. ([documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters))
- `status=$(some command)` -- the status variable hold the *output* of the command, not the exit status. The exit status is in the `$?` variable
- the `if` statement acts on *the exit status of the subsequent command* ([documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs))

  ```
  if some_comment; then action1; else action2; fi
  ```

  Most often, the command is `[` or `[[` to test some condition.

  However, `grep` has a clear exit status: 0 if the pattern was found, 1 otherwise. So you want this:

  ```
  if systemctl status asd.service | grep -q 'active'; then
      echo "$SERVICE was active"
  fi
  ```